# Extract Text and Metadata from pdfs and documents

Tags: javascript, python

I am making a plagiarism checker as a side project.
I am wondering on the approaches on how to extract the text and the related metadata from the documents, `such as bold text or big titles`.

I will use either python or javascript , with the frameworks on each language.

I am planning to support pdf and ms word documents.

So how could i extract the needed data form the documents?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember there is a library for the reading the word in doc file
you can usse python-docx2txt to extract the word in doc you can patse this in your terminal to install the library : pip install docx2txt

```
import docx2txt
readText = doc2txt.process("your_file_name")
print(readText)
```

not only that , if you wan to edit like add a new paragraph or add new table in the word file by using the program you can install the python-docx library to use the features ...about the PDF ermmm is out of my study alr....but i think you can try and check this out https://github.com/euske/pdfminer this maybe will give you ome idea : D

Comment: Thanks,
python-docx has the capabilities to extract the headers, and i think it also contains a font specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

There several Modules/packages to get the meta data from PDF

*** PDF MINER ***

1. PDFMiner is a text extraction tool for PDF documents.
2. Pure Python (3.6 or above).

   ```
   def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
       from pdfminer.converter              import TextConverter
       from pdfminer.pdfinterp              import PDFPageInterpreter
       from pdfminer.pdfinterp              import PDFResourceManager
       from pdfminer.pdfpage                import PDFPage
       import io,os,re
       import gc
       resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
       fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
       converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
       page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
       with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
           for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True,check_extractable=True):
               page_interpreter.process_page(page)
           text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
       converter.close()
       fake_file_handle.close()
       if text:
           return text

   extract_text_from_pdf("abc/xyz.pdf")
   ```

Using docx2txt to get the meta data from docx

*** DOCX2TXT ***

3. python-docx is a Python library for creating and updating Microsoft Word (.docx) files.
4. A pure python-based utility to extract text from docx files.

   ```
   import docx2txt

   # extract text
   text = docx2txt.process("file.docx")
   ```